# transparenting selection

Tags: gimp, transparency

How can I make selection transparent as value of selection by quick mask? I mean I made quick mask, made selection and now want these selected parts to be as transparent as much selected are.

Answer (score 0):

The quick-mask is meant to edit the selection channel rather than the image.

To modify your image, **untoggle quick-mask** (the selection will be preserved) and do what you'd normally do with a selection (**hit delete** to make selected regions transparent).